The upperbound of Shannon Entropy
I am currently working on an optimization problem, and I need to show that the Shannon entropy:$-\sum_{i=1}^{m}v_i\log(v_i)$ has upper bound $ m$ where $v_i\geq0 $ and $v^{T}1=1$. Despite searching online, I have been unable to find a clear proof for this result. Any guidance or references would be greatly appreciated.

It is a trivial optimization problem with one equality constraint. The concavity of $\log$ andJensen's inequality are more than enough to show the upper bound.

Doesn't it have an upper bound of $\log m$ rather than $m$?

@JohnBarber it does
